# Creating ID in HTML, linter shows error. Don't use IDs in selectors

Tags: html, css, linter

I created a few ID and classes on HTML and using CSS to change the appearance, the classes are doing fine but linter shows error for ID.

```
#unique {color: red;}
```

Here is the error -  Don't use IDs in selectors.

Comment: So, as the linter says, have you tried... not using an ID? (or disabling the linter rule?) Use a class instead, or something?

Comment: While using ID as a selector is valid, there are [arguments against using it as a selector](https://dev.to/claireparkerjones/reasons-not-to-use-ids-in-css-4ni4). Hence the linter error. At the very least it should be used sparingly and with caution.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally it can happen only if you use the same id for different elements. Check you markup again and if there are different elements using the same id, just change it, or it is better to use classes for setting styles. Linters should not through errors on css selectors.